# Select total count, not the filtered amount from the WHERE clause while keeping the filter

Tags: sql, sql-server

My company CMS records a record every time a page is viewed.

I'm trying to write a query that will return the total number of times that page has been viewed since the start of time, when there has been a page view since a certain time.

Here's what I've done, however this returns only the count since the specified time, not the count of all time.

```
SELECT PageId, COUNT(PageId) FROM PageViews
WHERE PageId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PageId WHERE [When] >= '2017-02-16 19:37:21.593'
 )
 GROUP BY PageId
```

`PageId` is ID of the page, not the ID of the view record.

Comment: Just remove the where condition in the inner query

Comment: Is PageId the id of the page, or the id of a single view record for the page?

Comment: It gives the count since the specified time because it is in the query. To get the count of all time, wouldn't you need to remove `[When] >= '2017-02-16 19:37:21.593'`?

Comment: @Tumen_t He needs to know the page was viewed after that time... then count of all time.

Comment: @MattSpinks updated; `PageId` is the ID of the page, not the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT PageId, 
   COUNT(PageId) -- count all rows
FROM PageViews
GROUP BY PageId
   -- return only those PageIds which have been visited lately
HAVING MAX([When]) >= '2017-02-16 19:37:21.593'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using `EXITS` to check if the page has been view for date and then find counts as required:

```
SELECT PageId, COUNT(PageId) FROM PageViews p1
WHERE exists (
    SELECT 1
    from PageViews p2
    WHERE p1.PageId = p2.PageId
    and [When] >= '2017-02-16 19:37:21.593'
 )
 GROUP BY PageId
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join between the total count and the counr for period

```
select a.PageId, COUNT(a.PageId) pageTotal, t1.pageCount
FROM PageViews as a
GROUP BY PageId
LEFT JOIN 
( SELECT PageId, COUNT(PageId)  pageNum FROM PageViews
WHERE PageId IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT PageId WHERE [When] >= '2017-02-16 19:37:21.593'
 )
 GROUP BY PageId ) t1.PageID on a.PageId
```